# Shopify: Display Related Products As A Slideshow

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to display related products using jQuery Cycle. The end goal is to display two products at once and the user can see the next two by clicking an arrow. so the code would be like

```
<ul><li>two products</li><li>two products</li><ul>.
```

I'm using this liquid code:

https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/1002801

But this puts one product in one li tag, and I need to know how I can put two products in one li tag.

I hope I'm clear.

Comment: You need to use the liquid function "cycle." In the first cycle write the <li> and in the second don't. that will put 2 images in each <li> http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#cycle

Comment: Thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @FunkDoc Thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll accept i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the liquid function "cycle." In the first cycle write the li and in the second don't. that will put 2 images in each li http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#cycle